# Bash: If statement nested in for loop

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

I am writing a simple script to check if an entered directory path exists. This is what I have

```
echo "Please specify complete directory path"
read file_path

for file in $file_path; do
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
        echo "$file is a directory"
        break
    else
        echo "$file is not a directory, please try again."
fi
done
```

What I need is if it is not a directory to go back and ask for the file path again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
echo "Please specify complete directory path"

while read file; do
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
        echo "$file is a directory"
        break
    fi
    echo "$file is not a directory, please try again."
done
```

Comment: Why not `while read file` instead of an infinite loop?  You do need to handle the EOF case somehow, but that's missing in the code anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 0):

No need to split the path into its parts, testing the entire path with -d will tell you whether or not it is a directory.  You need to put the entire test into a while loop until the user gets it right:

```
#/bin/sh
set -e
file_path=''
while [ ! -d "$file_path" ]
do
    echo "Please specify complete directory path"
    read file_path   
    if [ ! -d "$file_path" ]
    then
        echo "$file_path is not a directory, please try again."
    fi
done
```

I can use it like this

```
$ sh /tmp/test.sh 
Please specify complete directory path
foobar
foobar is not a directory, please try again.
Please specify complete directory path
/var/www
```